# javascript: xml to string in IE 10

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer-10

I'm working on modernizing this really old web application to work on modern browsers, and I have run into an issue with IE 10. Eventually I come to a point where I have to convert an XML document into a string:

```
function xmlToString(xmlElement)
{
     if (document.evaluate)
     {
          var serializer = new XMLSerializer()
          var strXml = serializer.serializeToString(xmlElement)
     }
     else
          var strXml = xmlElement.xml
}
```

The first if block is for Firefox and Chrome; that works fine. The line after the else is for Internet Explorer. It works fine on 8 and 9 but not 10 (and it has to work on all 3). From what i've gathered, this is because IE 10 moves away from the previous microsoft ways of handling xml to something closer to standard. However, I haven't found a replacement for the .xml property in IE 10 yet?

Does anyone know how I can convert an XML document into a string in IE 10?

Thanks.

EDIT: So the ACTUAL cause of the problem here is that in IE 10 the value of xmlElement.xml is undefined. Furthermore it wasn't converting the xml document to a string; that property already was a string representation of the xml document. Still need to figure out how to do this in IE 10 though.

EDIT 2: So I figured out the answer, but apparently im not allowed to actually answer my own question for several hours, so ill just copy it here for now:

AAAnd of course, about 5 minutes after I post this I finally figure out the right questions to ask Google... -_-

Anyway, turns out IE 9 and above supports the XMLSerializer, so it was a matter of figuring out how to detect that functionality without alienating any of the necessary browsers. [This page](http://jeffreifman.com/check-if-a-javascript-function-exists-or-is-defined/) showed me an awesome way of detecting javascript functionalities that got everything working.

Here is the final code, it works on IE 8 and 10 as well as the latest Chrome and Firefox:

```
function xmlToString(xmlElement)
{
    if (typeof XMLSerializer == 'function')
    {
        var serializer = new XMLSerializer()
        var strXml = serializer.serializeToString(xmlElement)
    }
    else
        var strXml = xmlElement.xml
}
```

The last line still has to be there for this to work on IE 8

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it using **`DOMParser`**.

```
function xmlToString(xmlElement)
{
     if (document.evaluate)
     {
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var strXml = parser.parseFromString(xmlElement, "text/xml");
     }
     else
        var strXml = xmlElement.xml
}
```

check this article about [**DOMParser and XMLSerializer**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/10/15/domparser-and-xmlserializer-in-ie9-beta.aspx)

Here is a [**demo**](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/DOMParserXMLSerializer/Default.html)

Answer (score 0):

Simply let IE10 use the first block (already used by Firefox and Chrome)